# Why cells(1,1) = 500 * 100 causes overflow but 50000*100 doesn't?

Tags: excel, vba

I just created a simple sub and it gives an overflow error. However, I don't see anything wrong with the code, and it is really weird since `50000*100` is much bigger than `500*100`.

```
sub add()
    'This will cause an overflow error
    cells(1,1) = 500 * 100
    'But this won't
    cells(2,2) = 50000 * 100
end sub
```

Comment: Interestingly it does NOT cause the overflow error if you specify 50000 instead of 500 * 100...

Comment: Hint: Try `CLng(500)*100`

Comment: Yeah I guess 500 and 100 are being handled as integers so the product is also being handled as an integer, and 50000 is over the 32767 limit so here we are.

Comment: @KFichter 16 bit signed type?

Answer (score 74, accepted):

Consider:

```
Sub add()
    'This works:
    Cells(1, 1) = CLng(500) * 100
    'as does this:
    Cells(2, 2) = 50000 * 100
End Sub
```

Evidently VBA was picking a default type of `Integer` for the first expression because that type is large enough to hold the literals on the right hand side. 50000 is too big for an `Integer` so it interprets it as a `Long`. `CLng` explicitly triggers a promotion to `Long`.

Comment: Or [shorthand](http://www.bettersolutions.com/vba/VUD113/NO333718332.htm) `Cells(1, 1) = 500& * 100&`

Comment: @AndrewD It's enough to add the ampersand to just ONE of the numbers: `500 * 100&`

Comment: @ExcelHero true, it will do implicit conversion - but I prefer to be explicit to be safe...if I'm reviewing code I consider an implicit to be a "smell" because sometimes people get the assumed result type wrong (I work in a number of languages and have got this wrong on a late night :( )

Answer (score 20):

The maximim value for a `Integer` is `32767` and since `50000` is more it is cast as a `Long` type. Thus the results fits in `Long` just fine. But in the first case everything is done with `Integer` types and it overflows.

```
(Integer=500) * (Integer=100) = (Integer=50000)  'Overflow
(Long=50000) * (Integer=100) = (Long=5000000)    'Ok
```

Answer (score 9):

This is because of how VBA evaluates mathematical expressions. The return type of expression will be the type of first operand in the expression or its nearest numeric type equivalent.
However, the final result may not fit in that return type and throw overflow error.

When you do 500*100 , return type is integer.
While when you do 50000*100 the return type of this expression is Long.

To avoid overflow error you can do an explicit cast to let it know your intentions

`CLng(500) * 100`

Answer (score 2):

i got the answer from the following link: [Link from microsoft](https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/kb/125900)

it seems that even I did not assign a type to the number, excel automatically assign one to it based on its length. Thus, 500 is defined as integer and the result 50,000 is too big for type integer. That's why.