# VBA Calculation - Simple Calculation

Tags: excel, vba, userform

I would appreciate it if someone could help in simple calculation using VBA. My current situation is that I would like to make a simple calculation as follows

```
area = inner_dia * height
```

when ever I enter for inner_dia,50 and height,50, the correct answer should be 2,500; however my answer is 15,300. Kindly assist me where I went wrong and where can I learn more to make complicated calculations using VBA (such as using natural log, pi, etc.)

Thank you in advance

Comment: Would be helpful, if you were to provided the full code you used.

Comment: Please show your type definition (your `Dim` statements)

Comment: Possible related question: http://stackoverflow.com/q/31816396/380384

Answer (score 0):

Write this in the immediate window:

```
inner_dia = 50
height = 50
area = inner_dia * height
?area
```

Edit:
CommandButton1 is the name of the command button
tb_height and tb_inner_dia are the textboxes.

```
Option Explicit

Private Sub CommandButton1_Click()
    MsgBox tb_height.Value * tb_inner_dia.Value
End Sub
```

Comment: Thank you for helping. However I forgot to mention that I am creating a userform thus it requires user to input value into height textbox and inner_dia textbox. Do I need to configure something to the textbox?

Comment: `inner_dia = 50` forces the type to be 16-bit integer. A better way would be `inner_dia = 50#` and `height = 50#` to force floating point numbers.

Comment: Hi guys. It seems I have found a very odd solution to my own problem. I found out out that naming my textbox as "height" is the problm. I was troubleshooting the problem and change the textbox name from "height" to "hei" and the calculation is alright. Can someone highlight to me what seems to be the problem? Is there any restriction in naming my textbox as height?

Answer (score 0):

Your text box returns string values. You need to convert the strings into floating point numbers, do the calculation and then format the answer.

See example below:

```
Dim inner_dia as Double, height as Double
inner_dia = Val(TextBox1.Text)
height = Val(TextBox2.Text)

Dim result as Double
result = inner_dia * height

TextBox3.Text = Format(result, "0.000")
```